# Making a list of phone numbers for UI from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I'm trying to list my database of phone number to the view but I can't figure out how to just capture the phone number from rails console?

I've tried commands like Person.find(:phone_number) and Person.find_by_phone_number(:all) but nothing seems to be getting what I need?

I essentially don't want this output... Rather just the number[image]

Comment: Each of those represents a Person object. If you want the phone number of each, call the `phone_number` method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `pluck`

E.g. `Person.pluck(:phone_number)`

[Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)